# R - use function n times on the same data set

Tags: r, for-loop, recurrence

What is the most efficient way to apply a function repetitively on the same data set and give the end result without using a for loop? e.g.

```
set.seed(123)

# create arbitrary data frame
mydf <- data.frame(a = rbinom(10, 5, .5), b = rbinom(10, 8, .5))

# silly function
Foo <- function(df) {
  df <- df * (1 + rnorm(1,0, .1))
  df <- df + 5
  df
}

# repeat function 5 times in a row on the same data frame
for (i in c(1:5)) {
  mydf <- Foo(mydf)
  mydf
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is any more efficient than a `for` loop, but it's an option: `doFoo <- function(df, n) { if (n == 0) return(df); Recall(Foo(df), n - 1); }; doFoo(mydf, 5)`

Comment: Here is other way where you just hide the for loop in a function. This is NOT faster than doing the for loop in OP's example, but might potentially make code more neat if these need to be applied in multiple places.
First just write a function to multiply function: `multiplier = function(f,n,...) {function(x,...) {for(i in 1:n) {x = f(x,...)}x}}`. 

Then it can be applied to any function like this `multiplier(Foo,10)(mydf)`

Comment: I think your example is too general. There might be cases where recursive functions may benefit from memoisation with the `memoise` package. If you had a very large dataframe or many many loops then `Rcpp` might be called for.

Comment: Do you want time efficiency or memory efficiency? (yeah, I know: both :-) ).   Anyway, if your function is vectorizable, rewrite it that way.  If not, use the `vectorize` function to do so; then run a time or memory test to see if it really helped.

Comment: @StephenHenderson: My current work is a projection of demographic changes, both deterministic (people age every year, i.e. age <- age + 1) and probabilistic (people join and leave the population with a certain probability). I will need to simulate the changes over a multi-year time span for a matrix consisting counts of people by age groups and other factors. It's not a very large data frame, maybe 50*100 fields. Does that help?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: To be honest, I just don't want to use a for loop because it's considered to be bad manners in the R context. But I'm looking for time efficiency, if I have to choose.

Comment: That "don't use a loop" meme originally meant "Hey, most things in `R` are vectorized.  Do it that way."   There's nothing wrong with a loop when vectorization is difficult or impossible; plus you can use the `parallel` and `foreach` multicore tools with a for-loop; not so much with a nested or anonymous  function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @nrussel; for the example given, using `Recall()` gives the most elegant code. Speed-wise, it is similar to the `for` loop.

```
doFoo <- function(df, n) {

           if (n == 0) return(df)

           Recall(Foo(df), n - 1)
         }

doFoo(mydf, 5)
```